# wrong positioning of figure with tabular in xelatex

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, xetex, crop

I recently updated MikTex and it seems Xelatex is not able to place figures correctly anymore. Before updating all figures were shown correctly.
I work with Texworks and Miktex 2.9

Here it is the code that I run:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{method1/}{method2/}{dpfig/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[trim=6cm 2.5cm 6cm 2.5cm,clip=true,width=0.33\textwidth]{figure1.eps}&
\includegraphics[trim=6cm 2.5cm 6cm 2.5cm,clip=true,width=0.33\textwidth]{figure2.eps}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Two figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
\end{figure}
```

With this code, figures are correctly trimmed and the relative position between figure 1 and figure 2 is maintained. However, the position in the document is wrong: figure are placed upper and more right than expected (as the bottom-left corner of the table was placed in the middle of the page).
The unusual thing is that this does not happen in draft mode and picture are shown centered as it would be.

I usually compile with Xelatex, Makeindex and Bibtex.

I hope to have been clear.. bye!

**EDIT**: Sorry, I forgot to add the images I prepared from the file that run that script:

[image: Picture wrong positioning]
[image: Draft mode, correct positioning]

Comment: I cannot see any problem with XeLaTeX under Linux. Make a screenshot of what you see. By the way: testing examples by yourself maybe a good idea ... ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I've added a missing directive (`\end{figure}`) in order to make your example compilable. Incidentally, what are the natural sizes of the images in `figure1.eps` and `figure2.eps`? If they're the same, then your example code does not create the problem issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem: clipping of eps files doesn't give the same result as with dvips or dvipdfmx or as in TL12 (which all give the same result as the clipping of a pdf). In TL13 the result is defective too. There the graphics is somehow outside its frame. miktex just updated xetex.def so this is probably the source of the problem. I tested with tiger.eps instead of the figures in the example.

Comment: Maybe related: the thread ["eps inclusion by dvipdfmx and xdvipdfmx"](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-May/033670.html) in mailing list for TeX Live last month.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Actually I was wrong: dvipdfmx gives the same (imho faulty) result as xetex if one doesn't forget to add the driver option. Also both driver files contains the new `\Ginclude@eps` suggested by Bruno. If I revert to the older definition everything works fine. (I can't reproduce the problem Akita mentioned, so I don't know what the change should do.).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I haven't tested this. From the description I would assume that the problems might arise, if the lower left corner of the bounding box is not `0 0`.

Comment: It seems to be the same problem depicted in the newsletter. However, I am not an expert in programming directly inside the Tex routines or `\Ginclude@eps`. Should I wait for a new update of Xelatex? or there is any other solution? maybe downgrading miktex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deplacement of your images  looks like the result I get with TL13 but not like my output with miktex. Nevertheless try if it works if you add this your preamble (after loading graphicx):

```
\makeatletter
\def\Ginclude@eps#1{%
 \message{<#1>}%
  \bgroup
  \def\@tempa{!}%
  \dimen@\Gin@req@width
  \dimen@ii.1bp%
  \divide\dimen@\dimen@ii
  \@tempdima\Gin@req@height
  \divide\@tempdima\dimen@ii
    \special{PSfile="#1"\space
      llx=\Gin@llx\space
      lly=\Gin@lly\space
      urx=\Gin@urx\space
      ury=\Gin@ury\space
      \ifx\Gin@scalex\@tempa\else rwi=\number\dimen@\space\fi
      \ifx\Gin@scaley\@tempa\else rhi=\number\@tempdima\space\fi
      \ifGin@clip clip\fi}%
  \egroup}
\makeatother
```

(This is the older definition of `\Ginclude@eps`.)

Comment: Great, it is excellent!! It works perfectly. So, just a further comment, can I expect they will correct the xetex package in the future? Can we consider it a bug?

Comment: "They" will correct the problem if someone notifies them. So make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did you report this?

Comment: @JosephWright: No, I asked the OP to do it. (also I didn't follow if there were graphicx updates in the various system - I was more interested in the textfont error message).

Comment: OK, this seems to be linked to http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-May/033670.html. I guess what needs to happen is to get some tests sorted: I'll look at it.