# Figure going too much into right in xelatex, not in latex

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, xetex

My problem is somewhat similar to [another question on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4434/15395)
. I tried the answer given there but it didn't solve my problem.

The problem is that my figure goes too much into right, even though I have used `\centering` command. This problem only comes on compiling with XeLaTex and not with Latex; I don't know why. The MWE will illustrate this. Here is code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.7cm, bottom=2.7cm, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\date{} 
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
 \centering      
\includegraphics [scale=0.5] {MWE.eps}
 \caption{Using centering}
 \end{figure*}

123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
 \centering
 \vbox{\vspace{1.8em}\includegraphics [scale=0.5] {MWE.eps}} 
 \caption{Using centering and vbox and vspace\{1.8em\}}
 \end{figure*}

123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
 \centering
 \hbox{\hspace{-0.4em}\includegraphics [scale=0.5] {MWE.eps}} 
 \caption{Using centering and hbox and hspace\{-4em\}}
 \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output using XeLatex (on windows)
[image]

Here is the output using Latex (on linux)
[image]

Here is the [MWE.eps](http://temp-share.com/show/gFHcdyxyY)   which is used in the example:

Comment: Can you provide us with the graphic file in question? Do you see any warnings in the log file?

Comment: I am sorry. I have now provided this file MWE.eps

Comment: XeLatex does not give any warning, I have checked the logfile.

Comment: No issues here (TeX Live 2013). I've used a big block of text to check the centring, as the short '123' business doesn't really show the margins properly. Which TeX system do you have installed?

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9 on windows. I have used latex on linux for 5 years. Only recently, I am forced to use it on windows and can't avoid.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117619/15395 solved my problem.

Comment: OK, I'll mark as a dupe. I'll also check to see what the status is on the driver: could be it's been updated and we have different versions.